# Inner class and two constructors

Tags: java

I am new to java.I came across this code somewhere on the internet.

```
  class FactoryOuter {

  FactoryInner[] fi = new FactoryInner[3];
  private int lastIndex = 0;
  private int x = 0;

  public FactoryOuter(int x)
  {
    this.x = x;
  }

  public int getX()
  {
    return x;
  }

  public void addInner(int y)
  {
    if (lastIndex < fi.length)
    {
      fi[lastIndex++] = new FactoryInner(y);
    }
    else throw new RuntimeException("FactoryInner array full");
  }

  public void list()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < fi.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.print("I can see into the inner class where y = " +
                       fi[i].y + " or call display: ");
      fi[i].display();
    }
  }

  public class FactoryInner
  {
    private int y;
    private FactoryInner(int y)
    {
      this.y = y;
    }
    public void display()
    {
      System.out.println("FactoryInner x =  " + x + " and y = " + y);
    }
  }
}

public class FactoryInnerOuter
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FactoryOuter fo = new FactoryOuter(1);
        fo.addInner(101);
        fo.addInner(102);
        fo.addInner(103);
        fo.list();
        //fo.addInner(104);
    }
}
```

The output of the above code is given below

```
I can see into the inner class where y = 101 or call display: FactoryInner x =  1 and y = 101
I can see into the inner class where y = 102 or call display: FactoryInner x =  1 and y = 102
I can see into the inner class where y = 103 or call display: FactoryInner x =  1 and y = 103
```

My questions are as follows

1) I see the constructor of `FactoryInner` class being called twice.The first instance apparently calls a default constructor as shown below.

```
 FactoryInner[] fi = new FactoryInner[3];
```

The second instance calls the constructor that is defined in the code.

```
fi[lastIndex++] = new FactoryInner(y);
```

Why does the code need two constructors? If I replace

```
FactoryInner[] fi = new FactoryInner[3]; with

FactoryInner[] fi;
```

I do get the following errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at FactoryOuter.addInner(FactoryInnerOuter.java:19)
    at FactoryInnerOuter.main(FactoryInnerOuter.java:56)
```

Why are two construcors needed ? Is this a particulary bad example?  Could someone please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is not a call to the constructer.
Here you are initializing an array of FactoryInner objects with room for three objects:

```
FactoryInner[] fi = new FactoryInner[3];
```

Here you are putting actual FactoryInner objects into the array, hence you need to give a value to the constructor because now you are actually initializing objects from the class FactoryInner:

```
fi[lastIndex++] = new FactoryInner(y);
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
fi[lastIndex++] = new FactoryInner(y);
```

Initializes the `FactoryInner` reference at index `lastIndex` in the `FactoryInner` array `fi`.

This

```
FactoryInner[] fi = new FactoryInner[3];
```

initializes the `fi` `FactoryInner` array. Notice the square brackets, `[]`.

You have to initialize the array first before you can initialize its elements. Otherwise you try to access a member of a `null` array reference and get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: is it safe to say that in java Type[] obj = new Type[N]; should always be there for all array declerations?

Comment: @liv2hak There is also another way to initialize arrays, with a `{...}` notation. Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)